# Customize the Sharepoint add list column page

Tags: sharepoint, list

I have defined a custom Sharepoint list for special attributes related to a software application inventory and installed it as a feature. I also want to group these attributes in categories. How could I change the Sharepoint page that allows the user to add a column to a list, so that when the user adds a column to my custom list type (column = attribute) he'll have a dropdown to choose the category?

Comment: I'd like to help, but I've read your Q several times and I'm just not sure what you are asking for. Can you try rephrasing your Q and be very precise.. e.g. you've defined a custom list -- did you define a list template or create a custom list? Why is it important that you installed it as a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to add a choice column data type thats already prepopulated so that users can then add it to their own content types?

have a look here, this is probably what you want to do: http://www.sharethispoint.com/archive/2006/08/07/23.aspx